# Creating a branch for release snapshots?

Tags: git

I have a git repository. I want to create a branch for release snapshots. Would work like this:

1. Currently working in my usual branch, named "foo".
2. Create a branch (one time), named "release".
3. Work for a bit on foo, committing changes etc.
4. Ready to cut a release of the app, push all changes from foo to release.
5. Repeat steps 3 & 4 from now on.

The purpose of "release" is to hold the state of the code for the last public release. If I discovered a bug a week after release, I could pull out that snap shot, patch and re-release.

Is there some other mechanism of doing this? I'm coming from subversion and wincvs, so any advice would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this is through tagging.  Work in any branch you like and when you are ready to release just tag the current head.

```
git tag MyProject_1_0
```

This can then be referenced at any later point to make changes from that point

```
git checkout MyProject_1_0
```

Note: When doing a push to your remote tags will not be pushed by default.  You need to use the --tags option to push the newly created tag so other users can download it later.

Comment: Ah that's not a bad idea - can you get a listing of tags in your repository to discover what's available then?

Comment: @user291701 you can use `git tag -l` to list all tags in your repository

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but I highly recommend the git workflow approach described here http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/.
It formalizes using branches such as release, hotfix, and master with tags.
There are even tools written expressly for this method: https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/tree/feature/python-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

I would use a tag like jared says, but use an annotated tag by giving `git tag` the `-a` flag.  This gives the tag a SHA, the ability to add some notes to the tag, as well as sign it.

This would guarantee that tag `tagName - SHA:abcd1234` came from that exact commit.